# Uploading and saving files in CakePHP 2.1

Tags: cakephp, uploader

I want to save my uploads in a specific folder for each app_id. For example, when an applicant with app_id of 45 uploads the files it must save in a folder named 45 whilst all his/her uploads such as birth certificate, college certificate, profile picture and high school certificate will be in that folder, same to the other app_id eg 89 must have his/her own folder but all the uploaded files will be located in one parent folder for example webroot/files/uploads/....

I managed to implement Uploader v3.6 from Miles Johnson, so any help on that plugin or any other solutions

Any tutorial or link to tackle this challenge

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A huge security fail in your idea is to store high school certificates in the public (!) accessible /webroot/files/uploads folder. You can be sure to get in pretty unpleasant situations in many countries that have privacy laws if everyone can download these proivate documents from your server.

Storing the files in folders 1, 2, 3... using the incremental ids is also a bad idea performance wise: Read the section "File System Performance" of [this article](http://cakedc.com/florian_kraemer/2010/01/25/file-uploading-file-storage-and-cakephp-mediaview-class).

Storing all files attached to a user in the same folder might be a good idea if you want to delete all of them in one action when you delete the user but you should not forget about sanitizing the file names properly. But again: If you store thousands of files in the same (sub) folder you might get into issues again.

For a file storage solution for CakePHP 2.x I can suggest you to read the readme.md of my [FileStorage plugin](https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage) that covers nearly all common problems and gives you a solid base for a file storage.

Comment: ok thanks for the contribution, but as a learning curve am still new to CakePHP, i would be grateful if you could show me how do i do that, saving files according to their user_id_directory, then i would have a good understanding of the mechanism.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not writing the code for you. It's plain simple: Save the record to the table, then you have the id, create the directory with that id and save the file to it.